# How to automate mouse clicks with conditions in AutoHotkey?

Tags: microsoft-excel, autohotkey

I work in Excel and I have to keep full screen mode on. For this I have automated mouse click like this:

```
F2::
MouseClick, left,  497,  45 ;clicks on view tab
Sleep, 100
MouseClick, left,  236,  94 ;clicks on full screen button
Sleep, 100
send EXCELDATA
return
```

It first clicks on view tab then it clicks on full screen button and then it sends EXCELDATA to the current selected cell. But here the problem is when Excel sheet is already in full screen mode then it clicks on these coordinates even and sends EXCELDATA at wrong cell. I want that if Excel sheet is already in full screen mode, then it should not click anywhere and it should only send EXCELDATA to the current selected cell. Is it possible using a single hotkey, like F2? Is there any command in AutoHotkey by which we can set the image or snapshoot of current scenario and set conditions that if Excel sheet is in so n so position then it should click on these coordinates otherwise send only EXCELDATA? I think imagesearch command can help in this regard but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: This needs to be much more clear and to the point. Your code does not even show what `EXCELDATA` is or where it comes from.

Comment: This is awfully close to being a duplicate of [How to use conditions in AutoHotkey?](http://superuser.com/q/897193/354511), posted three days earlier by the same user.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to set an "if" condition at the beginning of the script checking for fullscreen status via checking the resolution of the active window.

Comment: It seems to me that you're just telling the user to do the thing that he wants to do.  The question asks "How?"; you haven't answered that.

Comment: I gave the basic idea and the command he needs to (learn) to use via the manual.
If you're expecting me to spoil this person's adventure of learning AHK then I won't do it.